# Why gives Modulo of complex numbers different answers for rationals and reals

Tags: numerics, modular-arithmetic

When running

```
Table[1.*Mod[(1 + I)^(1 + k*I), 1 + k*I], {k, 49, 50, 0.5}]
Table[1.*Mod[(1 + I)^(1 + k*I), 1 + k*I], {k, 49, 50, 1/2}]
```

I get for the first table

```
{1.28398*10^-17 - 2.4145*10^-17 I, 1.1351*10^-17 - 1.45645*10^-17 I, 
 9.24544*10^-18 - 8.36557*10^-18 I}
```

and for the second table completely different values:

```
{-48. + 50. I, -48.5 + 50.5 I, -49. + 51. I}
```

In Mathematica 12.0.0.0. Any explanation?

Comment: `Mod` for approximate moduli just gives a result that lies within a disk of the minimal radius based on the modulus. With exact moduli there is a different normalization convention based on `Quotient`; see the Details and Options section on the reference page.

Comment: What Option settings are you referring to?

Comment: I made no claim about `Option` settings. Indeed, `Mod` takes no options.